# How to pop up modal and populate data in modal with one button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview connected to a database, and an preview button in each row. I need to find the id of the row that the button was clicked in, get all the data for that row from the database and display it in a pop up modal. So I need to have the modal pop up, call a method in C#, and find the row ID with one button click

Ive tried putting an href and a method call on the same button, didnt work. Ive tried calling the modal to pop up from within the method, didnt work. Ive tried calling javascript that makes the modal pop up from inside the method, didnt work.

Here is my asp gridview:

```
   <asp:GridView
   ID="GridView1"
   runat="server"
   OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">                              
   <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblID" Text='<%#Eval("PostID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>         
           <div class="dropdown">
           <button class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-no-arrow" type="button" id="btnDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-ight" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <asp:Button
                       Text="Preview"
                       type="Button"
                       class="dropdown-item"
                       ID="btnPreview"
                       runat="server"
                       CommandName="Preview"
                       CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                  </div>
                   </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the C# method it calls:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[index];
        Label id = selectedRow.FindControl("lblID") as Label;


        localDB.Open();

        if (e.CommandName == "Preview")
        {
            LoadPreview();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);

        }
    }
```

And here is load preview method:

```
 protected void LoadPreview()
    {
        try
        {

            localDB.Open();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getTitle = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getTitle.Connection = localDB;
            getTitle.CommandText = "Select Title From Post where PostID = @id";
            getTitle.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label1.InnerText = getTitle.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getDescription = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getDescription.Connection = localDB;
            getDescription.CommandText = "Select PostDescription From Post where PostID = @id";
            getDescription.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label2.InnerText = getDescription.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getResponsibilities = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getResponsibilities.Connection = localDB;
            getResponsibilities.CommandText = "Select Responsibilities From Job where PostID = @id";
            getResponsibilities.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label3.InnerText = getResponsibilities.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getQualifications = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getQualifications.Connection = localDB;
            getQualifications.CommandText = "Select Requirements From Job where PostID = @id";
            getQualifications.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label4.InnerText = getQualifications.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getDepartment = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getDepartment.Connection = localDB;
            getDepartment.CommandText = "Select Department From Job where PostID = @id";
            getDepartment.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label5.InnerText = getDepartment.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getLocation = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getLocation.Connection = localDB;
            getLocation.CommandText = "Select JobAddress From Job where PostID = @id";
            getLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label6.InnerText = getLocation.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getSalary = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getSalary.Connection = localDB;
            getSalary.CommandText = "Select Salary From Job where PostID = @id";
            getSalary.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label7.InnerText = getSalary.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getPayType = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getPayType.Connection = localDB;
            getPayType.CommandText = "Select PayType From Job where PostID = @id";
            getPayType.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label8.InnerText = getPayType.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getDueDate = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getDueDate.Connection = localDB;
            getDueDate.CommandText = "Select DueDate From Job where PostID = @id";
            getDueDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label9.InnerText = getDueDate.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand getday = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            getday.Connection = localDB;
            getday.CommandText = "Select ADayInTheLife From Job where PostID = @id";
            getday.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
            Label10.InnerText = getday.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


            localDB.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Label1.InnerText = "";
            Label2.InnerText = "";
            Label3.InnerText = "";
            Label4.InnerText = "";
            Label5.InnerText = "";
            Label6.InnerText = "";
            Label7.InnerText = "";
            Label8.InnerText = "";
            Label9.InnerText = "";
            Label10.InnerText = "";
        }

    }
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal3').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Preview modal

```
 <!-- Preview Modal HTML -->
            <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Preview Application</h4>
                      </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="bg-white space-sm">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <h2><label ID="Label1" runat="server" text=""></label></h2>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--end of section-->
                                <div>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                                            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-7">
                                                <article>
                                                    <h5>Role Description</h5>
                                                    <label ID="Label2" runat="server" text=""></label>
                                                    <h5>Responsibilities</h5>
                                                    <label ID="Label3" runat="server" text=""></label>
                                                    <h5>Minimum Qualifications</h5>
                                                    <label ID="Label4" runat="server" text=""></label>
                                                    <h5>A Day In The Life</h5>
                                                    <label ID="Label10" runat="server" text=""></label>
                                                </article>
                                                <hr>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--end of col-->
                                <div class="card full">
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush full">
                                        <li class="list-group-item full">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between full">
                                                <div><i class="icon-tools mr-1"></i>Department</div>
                                                <label id="Label5" runat="server" text=""></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <div><i class="icon-home mr-1"></i>Location</div>
                                                <label id="Label6" runat="server"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <div><i class="icon-calculator mr-1"></i>Salary</div>
                                                <label id="Label7" runat="server"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <div><i class="icon-stopwatch mr-1"></i>Basis</div>
                                                <label id="Label8" runat="server"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                                <div><i class="icon-calendar mr-1"></i>Due Date</div>
                                                <label id="Label9" runat="server"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Preview Modal-->
```

Comment: I added the javascript

Comment: Thanks for that. Now we need the HTML for `myModal3` so we can see if there's anything wrong in the HTML structure

Comment: I added the modal. I also have the javascript in the head of my html file. Is that ok for Visual Studio?